# Add pager on Top of Review page

Tags: feature-request, review

It would be nice to have the pager also on Top of the Review page (random ordering disabled) and not only on the bottom, so you could page throw the pages without scrolling to the bottom of the page. I´m always displaying 50 items per page. Also with only 15 items i need to scroll cause the Tag list on right needs so much space.